# Qt QTreeview currentChange is not emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I am trying to run some code when I select a new index in a QTreeView

**In RoverPlanner.h**

```
namespace Ui {
    class RoverPlanner;
}

class RoverPlanner : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit RoverPlanner(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void save_paths_from_tree(QTreeView* treeView);
    void load_paths_into_tree(QTreeView* treeView);
    std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> get_paths(const char* filename) const;
    void update_segment_editor();
    cuarl_path::Segment* addSegment();
    ~RoverPlanner();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void treeSelectionChanged(const QModelIndex& prevIndex, const QModelIndex& nextIndex);

private:
    Ui::RoverPlanner *ui;
};
```

**In RoverPlanner.cpp**

```
RoverPlanner::RoverPlanner(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::RoverPlanner)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPushButton* btnLoadPaths = this->findChild<QPushButton*>("btn_load_paths");
    QPushButton* btnSavePaths = this->findChild<QPushButton*>("btn_save_paths");
    QPushButton* btnExecutePath = this->findChild<QPushButton*>("btn_execute_path"  );
    QPushButton* btnAddSegment = this->findChild<QPushButton*>("btn_add_to_path");

    QTreeView* treeView = this->findChild<QTreeView*>("tree_paths");

    connect(btnLoadPaths, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]() { load_paths_into_tree(treeView); });

 connect(treeView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, &RoverPlanner::treeSelectionChanged); // This does not seem to properly bind the index chan

}

void RoverPlanner::treeSelectionChanged(const QModelIndex &prevIndex, const QModelIndex &nextIndex) {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
}

//other functions
```

When I click on the items, it does not output anything in the console 
[image]

I'm confused because this seems to be the way to correctly connect the treeview selected index changed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: IIRC, you need to re-connect each time you set a model for `TreeView`

Comment: Good point, the selectionModel() I get is probably not the correct one

Comment: I can confirm that this has fixed my issue! Thanks @PiotrSkotnicki

Answer (score 2):

*selectionModel* gets replaced each time a new model is set for `QTreeView`.

[void QAbstractItemView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel):

> This function will create and set a new selection model, replacing any model that was previously set with [setSelectionModel()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setSelectionModel).

That means you need to reconnect the `&QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged` signal each time you set a new model.